# QT threading. Using pyqt to setup the QtHelpEngine

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'd appreciate some help on using the QtHelpEngine. I've tried a few approaches with various results. Below is the code that seems most intuitive to me but I run in to threading problems. The problem I'm having now is to use QT signals to perform the necessary actions in the correct sequence.

The error I get is this:

> QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different
>   thread. (Parent is QHelpEngine(0x226f6143780), parent's thread is
>   QmlSearch(0x226f61382a0), current thread is QThread(0x226f61bda80)

I'd appreciate if someone could give me some advice on how to solve this or how the help engine is intended to be used.

Thanks!

```
from PyQt5 import QtHelp, QtCore
import sys
import time


class QmlSearch(QtCore.QThread):

    def run(self):
        # setup help engine
        qhcPath = 'C:/Users/jonoa/Documents/TEST.qhc'   # just a temporary test file
        self.qmlHelp = QtHelp.QHelpEngine(qhcPath)
        self.qmlHelp.setupFinished.connect(self.onSetupFinished)
        self.qmlHelp.setupData()

    def onSetupFinished(self):
        print('setup finished')
        # when setup is finished register documentation
        path2 = 'C:/Program Files/QT/Docs/Qt-5.7/qtquick.qch'   # an example test file
        self.qmlHelp.registerDocumentation(path2)

        # Then setup the search engine
        self.qmlSearch = self.qmlHelp.searchEngine()    # This is where the script breaks.
        self.qmlSearch.reindexDocumentation()

    def onIndexFinished(self):
        print('indexing finished')
        # create search query and perform search
        query = QtHelp.QHelpSearchQuery(0, ['rectangle'])
        self.qmlSearch.searchingFinished.connect(self.onSearchFinished)
        self.qmlSearch.search([query])

    def onSearchFinished(self):
        print('search finished')

        # print some of the hits and finish
        print([a for a in self.qmlSearch.hits(0, self.qmlSearch.hitCount()) if 'rectangle' in a[1].lower()])
        self.finished.emit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    thread = QmlSearch()
    thread.finished.connect(app.exit)
    thread.start()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The real question is why is this in a thread? Is QtHelp allowed to be run in a secondary thread? Either way, I suspect the issue has something to do with the `run` method and the other slots not all executing in the same thread. I would suggest you do some debugging and find out exactly what threads everything is executing in, or possibly remove the threads entirely.

Comment: This is the only way I know to run QT without a GUI (that may sound strange but I'm trying to build a help system for my text editor as a learning project). I got this to work when I manually added pauses in order to wait for the setup, indexing and searching to finish, (instead of triggering with signals) but that's obviously a very ugly hack.

Comment: You shouldn't need threads to run QT without a GUI. You are already calling `app.exec_()` which launches the Qt event loop (which will prevent program termination). Does it not just work if you inherit from `QObject` instead and rename `run` to `__init__`?